# Styling ng-bootstrap [ngb-tab] in Angular 4

Tags: angular, background-color, ng-bootstrap

Tried to change the background color of [ngb-tab] through the css file but it does not changed.
Perhaps different approach required?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the nav-link and nav-link:hover properties

For example:

```
.nav-link{
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover{
  background-color: #72B626;
  color: #333333;
}
```